# How to dynamically pass connectionstrings in EF5

Tags: wpf, vb.net, entity-framework-5

I'm struggling with a project, converted to .net 4.5.

I have some functions like this:

```
Public Shared Function Load(iJaar As Integer, iKwartaal As Integer) As List(Of LoonDetail_121)
    Dim oLoonDetails As New List(Of LoonDetail_121)
    Try
         Dim oDB As New SDWMasterSDWDBEntities(DBConnections.ConnStringPrisma)
         Dim dStartDate As New Date(iJaar, ((iKwartaal - 1) * 3) + 1, 1)
         Dim dEndDate As New Date(iJaar, ((iKwartaal - 1) * 3) + 4, 1)

         oLoonDetails = oDB.LoonDetail_121.Where(Function(x) x.EindPeriode_121 >= dStartDate And
                                              x.EindPeriode_121 < dEndDate).ToList
     Catch ex As Exception
         Throw New Exception(GetCurrentMethod.Name & " " & ex.Message)
     End Try
     Return oLoonDetails
 End Function
```

When I convert this function to EF5, I get errors, since my SDCDBLonenEntities is not inherited anymore from ObjectContext, but it is inherited from DbContext.
Before, EF automatically created a constructor where I can pass my Connection String.
This is very easy, because I use different connectionstrings, depending on my Solution Configuration (Debug/Release).
In EF5, the constructor doesn't accept Connectionstrings anymore.
I tried to create a partial class of my Entity, and create my own constructor, but I can't get this working:

```
Partial Public Class SDWMasterSDWDBEntities
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New(sConnString As String)
        MyBase.New(sConnString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

For another project, I adapted my Project-file to use different app.config files for each solution configuration, but that was a p.i.t.a to maintain and for me not a clean solution.

So my question is: How can I use EF5 with my own personal Connectionstrings?

These are my Connection Strings by the way:

```
#If DEBUG Then
    Friend ConnStringSDW As String = "metadata=res://*/Entities.SDWDB.csdl|res://*/Entities.SDWDB.ssdl|res://*/Entities.SDWDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=SDWDB01\SDWSQL;initial catalog=SDWDB_DEV;persist security info=True;user id=usr;password=pwd;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework'"
#Else
    Friend ConnStringSDW As String = "metadata=res://*/Entities.SDWDB.csdl|res://*/Entities.SDWDB.ssdl|res://*/Entities.SDWDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=SDWDB01\SDWSQL;initial catalog=SDWDB_PROD;persist security info=True;user id=usr;password=pwd;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework'"
#End If
```

And I get the error "The entity type SDW_USERS_MASTER is not part of the model for the current context.", when I execute this function:

```
Public Shared Function LoadAll() As List(Of SDW_USERS_MASTER)
    Dim oUsers As New List(Of SDW_USERS_MASTER)
    Try
        Using oDB As New SDWMaster.SDWMasterSDWDBEntities(DBConnections.ConnStringSDW)
            oUsers = (From tmpUsers In oDB.SDW_USERS_MASTER
                         Select tmpUsers).ToList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Login).ToList
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message)
        Throw New Exception(GetCurrentMethod.Name & " " & ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return oUsers
End Function
```

Comment: I already found the following: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/92c0129e-40dc-488c-a836-7e30846dfb30?SRC=VSIDE, but this only changes how the auto-generated code is created. I haven't tried it yet, since this is "going back to the older way", and microsoft doesn't advice it ...

Comment: If the database schemas are the same, you should be able to use the debug and release web or app configs to change what db it points too.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new partial class with the same name as your context, then overload the constructor.  So, if your context class is named "myContext", then you would have:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure
Imports System.Data.Objects
Imports System.Data.Objects.DataClasses
Imports System.Linq

Partial Public Class myContext
  Inherits DbContext

  Public Sub New(connectionString As String)
    MyBase.New(connectionString)
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That's what I do, but I keep having error "The entity type SDW_USERS_MASTER is not part of the model for the current context."